# How to find a value in a list of python dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Have a list of python dictionaries in the following format. How would you do a search to find a specific name exists?

```
label = [{'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 17, 8, 56, 24, 2347),
          'name': 'Test',
          'pos': 6},
             {'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 17, 8, 56, 24, 2347),
              'name': 'Name 2',
          'pos': 1}]
```

The following did not work:

```
if 'Test'  in label[name]

'Test' in label.values()
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You'd have to search through all dictionaries in your list; use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression:

```
any(d['name'] == 'Test' for d in label)
```

This will short circuit; return `True` when the *first* match is found, or return `False` if none of the dictionaries match.

Comment: You may want `('name' in d) and d['name']==query` if the `'name'` field might not exist. (`d.get('name')==query` is shorter but would return a false positive if query==None, if for some weird reason the name field could be None)

Answer (score 41):

You might also be after:

```
>>> match = next((l for l in label if l['name'] == 'Test'), None)
>>> print match
{'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 17, 8, 56, 24, 2347),
 'name': 'Test',
 'pos': 6}
```

Or possibly more clearly:

```
match = None
for l in label:
    if l['name'] == 'Test':
        match = l
        break
```